# Nextjs paths to an eCommerce

Tags: next.js

On the main page of my eCommerce I have this piece of code, that suppose to direct the user to the exact product that it's been clicked.

```
      {products.map((product) => (
        <Link href={`/products/${product.slug}`} key={product.id}>
          <ProductCard
            title={product.title}
            price={product.price}
            img={product.img}
          />
        </Link>
      ))}
```

And the route seems to work, if i hover on top of the product, the path seems correct (/products/1, products/2...), i got this by making the product page dynamic. But if clicked it goes to 404. What I needed is according to the clicked product, the dynamic page should load this template page with the right props, picture and text are the only thing that is should be changing. How should I proceed?